# What are some good examples of web 2.0 sites that use nHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

Are there any live, web 2.0 type applications that use nHibernate?

Looking for some real world usage on a high traffic web site/service.

Comment: If you are interested how ORM mappers scale, take a look at StackOverflow (Linq2Sql). I'm not sure how much faster/slower nHibernate is, but there shouldn't be big difference.

Answer (score 1):

Check out posts in the [NHibernate usage survey](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=952439).

As it looks from survey, [FoodCandy](http://www.foodcandy.com/) ("Food Social Network") is supposed to be built with NHib and capable of scaling to millions of users.